# Jailing and BackOff in Network Security

Tags: network-security, dictionary-attack

How can Jailing and Backoff be used to demotivate online dictionary attack in an authentication system?

Comment: Need more information

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary attacks means Trial-and-error from a list of potential passwords. Jailing and Backoff helps to slow down these attacks.

**Jailing** - Allow in, but restrict activities. It has interesting connections with access control.
**Backoff** - The most common form is the exponential backoff.

Let x be a parameter selected by the administrator; the system waits x^0 = 1 second before re prompting the user, after n failures the system waits x^(n-1) seconds.